# How to avoid duplicate key when insert getdate()

Tags: sql, database, sybase

I have a table `TransactionLog` with primary key `transaction_datetime`. There are many transactions calling the service to insert record into this table.

The following shows part of the stored procedure which the service will call in order to insert the record to the table. As there are many transactions calling the service simultaneously, it will cause duplicate key problem. So I wonder what is the best solution to insert all the rows without any duplicate key problem. I am using Sybase as database.

```
insert into TransactionLog
values (getdate(), @logmessage)
```

Comment: Never use a datetime column as primary key. Primary keys should be unique. Especially datetime values in a small range can easily become identic or at least look as if they were. Add an id column and use a sequence or auto increment to increase it.

Comment: yes, i know, but the table schema was set long time ago. i cannot change the schema now. is there any work around for solving this problem. thank you

Comment: Make the PK a combination of columns that will uniquely identify each record. If there is no such combination and you can’t and a new id column then there is no solution

Comment: is it feasible to add retry mechanism in store procedure to reduce the duplicate problem?

Comment: That doesn’t sound like a good idea to me as you’d have constant clashes/retries and it would be very inefficient - and you’re still just addressing symptom rather than the underlying cause

Comment: Even though, the table was designed long time ago, this design doesn't work. As simple as that. I think it's time to face reality (to be brutally honest) and change the table.

Comment: if you cannot change table schema, try: create sequence with maxvalue 100 and cilce, trunctate getdate() to seconds and add sequence value as millisecond.  This certainly doesn't look serious, but you can try.

Comment: *`I cannot change the schema now`* ... can you remove the PK constraint (which in turn will remove the associated unique index) and replace with a non-unique index?